# Grouping text and rect

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have several groups formed by a rects and a text

```
var dataset = [
    {'rect':{ id:1 ,color:'green', posX:20, posY: 20},
    'text':{ id:1 ,title: 'Home', texto:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores minima unde magni enim vel atque! Ratione amet reiciendis incidunt, mollitia iste magnam natus, dolores unde nemo consequuntur cumque labore minus!'},
    },
    ...
];
```

I add rect and text to several groups but
I can not see the text.

```
var myGroups = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .each(function(d) {
        d3.select(this).append("rect")
            .attr('class', 'rects')
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return d.rect.posX;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return d.rect.posY;
            })
            .attr("width", 160)
            .attr("height", 40)
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return d.rect.color;
            })
        d3.select(this).append("text")
            .attr('class', 'titles')
            .attr("x", 200)
            .attr("y", 300)
            .attr("width", 160)
            .attr("height", 40)
            .style('color', 'white')
            .style('font-family', 'Roboto')
            .attr('text', function(d) {
                return d.text.title
            })

    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SVG `<text>` elements have no attribute named `text`.

Therefore, instead of:

```
.attr('text', function(d) {
    return d.text.title
})
```

It should be:

```
.text(function(d) {
    return d.text.title
})
```

PS: not related to your question, but you don't need that `each` to append the rectangles and the texts. That's not the idiomatic D3. Just create an "enter" selection for both rectangles and texts doing:

```
myGroups.append("rect")
    .attr('class','rects')
    //etc...

myGroups.append("text")
    .attr('class','titles')
    //etc...
```